# ¿Por qué me aparece el mensaje de error "No pyvenv.cfg file" en PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Cuando ejecuto un programa en pycharm me sale este mensaje:

> No pyvenv.cfg file

Hace unos días todos los programas se ejecutaban pero ahora ninguno lo hace, me aseguré que los códigos estuvieran correctos pero no se soluciona.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta esto:

1. Ve al menú "Preferencias"
2. Abre pestaña "Proyecto" (Suele estar como Project:nombre_de_tu_proyecto
3. Selecciona "Interprete de proyecto" 
   Del lado derecho aparecerá el error de [invalid] en el input de la ruta del intérprete y junto un icono de engrane 
   3.1 Clic en el engrane y seleccionas "Add". 
   3.2 Selecciona "New environment" y botón OK

*Aquí se comenzará a crear todo ambiente del venv* y deberá salir una pantalla más o menos así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de esto ya tendrás creado el archivo pyvenv.cfg dentro de tu entorno de trabajo y lo puedes verificar en el ramificado de tu proyecto pues aparecerá ahora una carpeta llamada ***venv*** y dentro el archivo pyvenv.cfg

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de todo eso ya no debería salirte ese error a menos que tengas cruzados algunos proyectos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si funcionó